# how to do an drupal form submit using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-6

i have a custom module, in which i am submitting the form using drupal submit. ie using mymodule_submit() function. i want to ajaxify this submit using jquery. what all are the prerequisites for ajaxifying in drupal ? how to return the values and all?
somebody please help . thanks in advance

Comment: Can't believe you haven't gotten a single decent response on this- any updates on your end?

Answer (score 1):

Several high-level concepts are important:

- do it trough forms api. technically you can circumvent it and write your own form-tags (in plain HTML) but that brings more problems then its worth.
- changing the behaviour of any form, is done in a so called [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter)
- Changing the look [and feel](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) of any form is done in the [theme layer](http://drupal.org/node/290431)
- Then you can add ajaxified behaviour to a theme using [AHAH](http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/getting-going-ahah-and-drupal-6). Note that in Drupal AHAH is slightly misnamed: it is only a particular subset and works only for forms.

Comment: Not using the form API, and generating the HTML is considered a security issue.

Comment: The question is about ajaxifying form submission- you're talking about form generation.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1. If you dont need to capture the submit response: 
   Create a hidden iframe, and change the "target" attribute of the form to the iframe name. 
   This can be done in 2 javascript lines, after form rendering.
2. If you need to capture response:
   Use Jquery form plugin, so after submit you need to give a callback function passing he response as argument.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/examples

- you can refer to example module. It contains different types of ajax forms